# Nero Alternative? Or Soultion to my problem

Tags: video, burning, divx, nero

When I was on XP I used Nero 6. It worked fine never had problems. I am now on windows 7 and I am using Nero BurnLite 10 and it does not work.

I have DVD burner and a dvd player that plays divx files. I had a .avi file that is in XVID format so it should play in my dvd player.

I burned the file as a data file and tried to play it. The file would not load up at all. I got no errors or anything through the burn process nor when the file failed to load up in the dvd player.

I then too the exact same file, dvd-rw and went to my other computer that is still running XP and that had nero 6 on it. I burned it as a datafile like I alway have done and it ran just fine.

So I don't know if this is a nero problem or a hardware problem or what.

So I am not sure if I should try an alternative(not sure what is good) or what I should do to proceed to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of them will suggest you CDBurner XP. However my personal favorite is InfraRecorder that I use on Windows 7. Here is the link for you http://infrarecorder.org/ It is free and open source with GPL3 licensed.

Comment: CDBunerXP did not even work for me. Took forever to load up the program and kept crashing. Infrarecorder seems to work though!

Answer (score 1):

Try CDBurner XP

http://cdburnerxp.se/

.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 comes with a built in file burner as well as ISO burner. The only software I have purchased for burning is Clone CD, for creating ISOs. (Alternatively, there are plenty of free applications available to create ISOs as well.)

I use to use Nero as well back in the XP days. But not anymore, since everything I need to do is built into the Operating System. I know there are more advanced features I am missing out on, but I never used them anyways.

My suggestion would be to try and burn a different DivX and see if you experience the same problem. It could be a bad encode, or the encoders used a codec other than DivX (even though it ends in the .avi container extension.) Try taking a DivX you KNOW works (already burned) and reburning it with your new software.

There are a few programs out there to tell you which codecs a video has been encoded with. Try googling Veedub. It is a program that I use to manipulate AVIs. There is an info screen that gives you the details regarding the video and audio codecs of a loaded project.

Comment: So Windows 7 can burn divx files? Like I mentioned in my post I took the exact same file to my other computer(that runs nero 6 and xp) and used the same dvd-rw and it worked after it finished burning.

Comment: Are you using the same media in both computers? I am assuming you are using CD-Rs (not CD-RWs or DVDs). You are taking stand alone DivX files, dropping them onto a data disc, and burning - NOT converting media into DivX. Correct? If so, yes, you can do this right with Windows. Put a blank disc in and then use the Autolaunch options to access Windows 7's disc burner.

Comment: Ya just taking a divx file and burning it straight onto a dvd.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problem. Please try it and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) for your burning. Another thing to see is what speed Nero is running your DVD burner at, as I have sometimes found that burning at a very high speed can result in minor data corruption. If you have time to kill, try burning it at 4x or 8x and see if it works.